# Wireless Networking in Windows Server Core 2016

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-server-2016

So, according to this webpage, Windows Server Core does not support Wireness-Networking feature, [webpage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-removed-roles), but is there any way I can install the Wireless-Networking feature on a Windows Server Core 2016 PC?

Answer (score 2):

For stability, Servers normally require Wired Ethernet so they can reliably handle DHCP and DNS. If you wish to try wireless, you need a card / USB adapter with Server 2016 Drivers. I do not suggest this. Ethernet is much better.

Comment: I am using Server Core 2016 as if it were a normal PC, so I need the wireless networking capability (My laptop doesn't even have a ethernet port)

Comment: You can get a wireless USB card, but you need one with drivers and that might present an issue. You can also get USB Wired network cards and that may be better.

Comment: Not too many laptops do not have an Ethernet port. Mine does not. So Lenovo supplies a special port and dongle for this purpose.

Comment: If you're running a "normal PC" you aren't running Core.